# Is there a simple UNIX command for finding out how many cores I have to work with?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, multi-core, core

I've got an Ubuntu VM on my Mac. Is there a command I can run in Ubuntu that will tell me how many cores I have to work with?

I could do "about this mac" on the host, but I'm not sure how well the multi-core processor would translate to the VM.

Comment: You have configured your VM to have more than CPU, right? (Just making sure)

Answer (score 26):

This should work:

```
grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo
```

or

```
lshw -class processor -short
```

Comment: I tried the `grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo` and the output was 4. I'm confused because my box has an i3 in it, and I thought those were dual cores.

Comment: @Islay: It's because it's hyperthreaded.

Answer (score 5):

On OS X you can use sysctl or system_profiler:

```
$ sysctl hw.ncpu hw.physicalcpu hw.logicalcpu
hw.ncpu: 8
hw.physicalcpu: 4
hw.logicalcpu: 8
$ sysctl -n hw.ncpu # -n disables printing the names of variables
8
$ system_profiler SPHardwareDataType|grep Cores
      Total Number of Cores: 4
```

My processor supports hyper-threading, so there are 8 logical cores and 4 physical cores.

Answer (score 1):

This command will do the job:  dmesg | grep cpu

Comment: Nopes. This just shows all messages relating to CPU. Check above answers or use lscpu

Answer (score 0):

lscpu would list out the CPUs and their cores.